# How to construct a random variable with finite Lp norm but infinite Lq norm for all q>p?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I need to construct a random variable $X$ such that the $L^p$ norm $\|X\|_p<\infty$ for an arbitrary $p\geq1$ but has infinite $L^q$ norm $\|X\|_q=\infty$ for all $q>p$.

I've tried every combination of elementary functions I can think of and can't quite get something that works. Any help or hints would be appreciated. Even just a hint in the right direction would be nice. I've been stuck thinking about this for over 24 hours now.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln^2(1+x)}dx$ is finite, but for any $\alpha > 0$, $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x\ln^2(1+x)}dx$ is not.